# How to return a char** as a function argument

Tags: c, pointers, char, return-value, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a function that returns a pointer to pointers of chars (`char**`). The function takes 2 arguments

- `int* num_paths`: a pointer to an integer to indicate the number of strings to be returned.
- `int* errno`: a pointer to an integer to indicate an error code. This can contain different values, so I cannot simply check if `NULL` is returned in case of error.

Some example code is written below (with the majority of error checks omitted for simplicity):

```
char** get_paths(int* num_paths, int* errno) {
    char* path1 = NULL;
    char* path2 = NULL;
    char** paths = NULL;

    if(errno == NULL) {
        printf("Set errno in case of error, but cannot dereference NULL pointer\n");
        goto exit;
    }

    path1 = calloc(1, strlen("foo") + 1);
    path2 = calloc(1, strlen("bar") + 1);

    strcpy(path1, "foo");
    strcpy(path2, "bar");

    *num_paths = 2;
    paths = calloc(1, *num_paths*sizeof(char *));
    paths[0] = path1;
    paths[1] = path2;

    *errno = 0;
exit:
    return paths;
}

int main(void) {
    char** paths = NULL;
    int num_paths = 0;
    int errno = 0;

    paths = get_paths(&num_paths, &errno);
    if(errno != 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < num_paths; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", paths[i]);
        free(paths[i]);
    }
    free(paths);
}
```

The problem I have with this is that I can't set the error code in case a NULL pointer is passed as argument for `errno`. You could argue that this is a user error, but I would still like to avoid this situation in the first place.

So my question is: can I rewrite my `get_paths` function such that it returns an integer as error code, but also returns a `char**` through the function arguments without resorting to `char***` like in the following example:

```
int get_paths_3(char*** paths, int* num_paths) {
    char* path1 = NULL;
    char* path2 = NULL;

    path1 = calloc(1, strlen("foo") + 1);
    path2 = calloc(1, strlen("bar") + 1);

    strcpy(path1, "foo");
    strcpy(path2, "bar");

    *num_paths = 2;
    *paths = calloc(1, *num_paths*sizeof(char *));
    (*paths)[0] = path1;
    (*paths)[1] = path2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't set the number of paths if *that* pointer is `NULL` either. I don't see why you can't document the function: `NULL` pointer arguments not allowed.

Comment: The correct way to "return a `char**` through the function arguments" is to resort to a `char***` parameter. There are plenty of ways to design this function, but the design choice largely dictates what the function signature needs to be.

Comment: I wouldn't use `errno` as a variable name. The standard `<errno.h>` header (which is indirectly included from lots of other places) `#define`-s it as a macro.

Comment: You can maybe wrap both the pointer and the integer in a `struct` and return that.

Comment: In general, I'd offload the error handling about trivial stuff like "error if NULL is passed as parameter" to the caller. Simply document the function instead: "If you pass NULL to this parameter, then you are f****d". Various such sanity checks and defensive programming should be done on the caller side.

Comment: Everything will definitely be documented properly, but there is no way to guarantee that documentation will be read. I just need to make sure there will never be `NULL` pointer dereferences in my code and preferably return an error code if something is wrong such that the caller is informed.

Comment: I'll avoid using `errno` as a variable to prevent mixing things up. I cannot use things like `char***` because that will never pass our code style checks, so I was wondering if there was a good alternative.

Comment: @Johan It wouldn't be in your code. If I make a call such as `strcpy(NULL, NULL);` then the problem is with the caller, not the implementation of `strcpy`. It's not your application logic's job to sanitize various crappy pointers on the caller side.

Comment: Btw minor nit-pick: don't use calloc if you intend to overwrite the data anyway. Use malloc for such cases, for a minor speed improvement.

Comment: @Lundin using calloc is more of a habit to ensure that data is always initialized, but since I'm overwriting it immediately afterwards, a malloc is probably better. I'll keep it in mind for real situations, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much the only case where "three star" pointers are fine to use. It's fairly common practice in API design to reserve the return value for error codes, so this situation isn't uncommon.

There are alternatives, but they are arguably not much better. You could abuse the fact that `void*` can be converted to/from `char**` but it isn't much prettier and less type safe:

```
// not recommended

int get_paths_4 (void** paths, size_t* num_paths)
{
    char* path1 = calloc(1, strlen("foo") + 1);
    char* path2 = calloc(1, strlen("bar") + 1);

    strcpy(path1, "foo");
    strcpy(path2, "bar");

    *num_paths = 2;
    char** path_array;
    path_array= calloc(1, *num_paths*sizeof(char *));
    path_array[0] = path1;
    path_array[1] = path2;
    *paths = path_array;
    return 0;
}

...

void* vptr;
size_t n;

get_paths_4 (&vptr, &n);
char** paths = vptr;

for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  puts(paths[i]);
}
```

A more sound alternative might be wrap all your parameters into a single `struct` type and pass that one as a pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting discussion. It's been very helpful. I'll either stick to my original implementation or apply the "three star" pointer solution if that gets accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot mixing return types in C is a terrible mistake and should not be done, you can either:

- return the pointer you need and add a error code to a variable
- return the error code and add the pointer to a variable

Both are valid strategies and I'd pick the one that matches the rest of your code to have consistency.